# how to replace an expression by another one using regex in pig

Tags: regex, hadoop, apache-pig

i'm using regex tu extract the name :

```
" REGISTER piggybank.jar
A = LOAD 'table_DHCP' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
B = foreach A  generate REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL (name,'.*-(.*).engtp.dz$');
dump B; "
```

the  expression was before  like :departement-name.engtp.dz and i use regex to extract only the name in the colomn name ,
but now i would like to replace the "departement-name.engtp.dz" by the expression that regex give me so how can i do that with regex ?! please

Comment: can you please provide an input with a desired output ?

Comment: juste an exemple  input =DCL-GUETTACHE.engtp.dz output GUETTACHE

Answer (score 0):

Use [replace](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/func.html#replace) function, if you are familiar with Java, replace in Pig is just an implementation of [replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) in Java.

Then use a capturing group reference:

```
REPLACE(name, '.*-(.*).engtp.dz$', '$1');
```

Comment: yes put you know the problem is in newchar because i'm using a variable  !  B = foreach A  generate REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL (name,'.*-(.*).engtp.dz$')  so the new caractère is B and  i wana replace the expression in the clomn name